# How to solve a differential equation of second order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How one can solve ODE in the following general form?
$$f(x)\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+g(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+h(x)(\frac{dy}{dx})^{2}=0$$
where $f$, $g$ and $h$ are continous functions of $x$.

My solution: Let $y=e^{\int u(x)dx}$, then we have
$$y'=u e^{\int u(x)dx}$$
and
$$ y''= (u'+u^{2})e^{\int u(x)dx}$$
Substituting the above equations into differential equation, we get a differential equation as follow
$$f(x)(u'+u^{2}) + g(x) u + h(x) u^{2} e^{\int u(x)dx}=0$$ 
This is where I stop!?

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z(x)=y'(x)$. The equation is

$$f(x)z'(x)+g(x)z(x)+h(x)z^2(x)=0.$$

Using the integrand factor for the linear terms $i(x)=\exp\left(\int\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)}\,dx\right)$, we turn it to

$$(i(x)z(x))'+\frac{i(x)h(x)}{f(x)}z^2(x)=0.$$
Then setting $w(x)=i(x)z(x)$, we get a separable equation

$$w'(x)+\frac{h(x)}{i(x)f(x)}w^2(x)=0,$$
solved as

$$\frac1{w(x)}=\int\frac{h(x)}{i(x)f(x)}\,dx.$$

Comment: Note that line 4 must be written as $(ifz)' - if'z+ihz^{2}=0$

Comment: Thanks for the notice, the integrating factor was wrongly used. (And maybe it is still :-) , but the method works anyway.)